# An Include inside an if statement in Joomla-PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, joomla, include, joomla2.5

Im adding php inside an article using DirectPHP plugin.
My goal is to create a script that will include a file with text when the user has member = true; and when not to not show anything.

I have added this piece of code in a module in the top next to the logo:

```
<?php
if ($user =JFactory::getUser()->guest)
{
$member = false;
echo "Welcome guest, sign up and read nice quotes";
}
else
   {
$member = true;
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
echo "Welcome " . $user->username;
}
?>
```

- I have set member = true; now that the person has signed in. If he isnt signed in its on false.

Then inside the article I have:

```
<?php
if ($member == false)
{
 $file = file_get_contents ('quotes/quotes.html'); 
 echo $file;
}
?>

<hr id="system-readmore" />

<?php 
if ($member == true)
{
include_once JPATH_SITE.'/quotes/random.php';
echo ShowQuotes(); 
}
?>
```

I cant find the problem making this not run. The quotes are shown for both `$member = false;` and `$member = true;` Are includes always being parsed despite the if statement? Same goes for file_get_contents?  I tried to see if the $member declaration from the header is being kept within the parsing and wrote:

```
<?php
if ($member = true)
{
echo "Logged in";
}
?>
```

and it worked good so the problem is within the `include_once` and `file_get_contents`, I tried to pinpoint it as much as I can.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Ay ay. Variables are not passed between your module and that article php. And there are many other issues in your code, like assignment in `if`, then assignments instead of comparison etc. If you take some time to learn the basics like I advised you before, you will accomplish what you want much faster ;)

Comment: I did I finished reading about if statements and I'm now trying to find out what the problem is cause its very puzzling it seems it should work fine. :/

Comment: now you need to read about variable scope. but to make it short, you need to check in your article php again if member is logged in, because your variable from the module is not available there. finish books/tutorials first, then start coding something like this! :)

Comment: If I dont write some code to see it live and learn from mistakes I cant learn. Im trying to put in live examples the things I have learned so far :D So you are saying I should set $member as a global variable so that the module and the article share access to it?

Comment: Nooo, I am not saying that. I am saying to check again in your article if member is a guest. And start learning from mistakes **after** you finish the basic reading. Just have some patience, otherwise you waste not only your time, but of the people here too :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your issue:

```
if ($member = true)
{
echo "Logged in";
}
```

This is always assigning the value of `true` to `$member`.

Also here:

```
if ($user =JFactory::getUser()->guest)
```

You might have the same assignment problem (not sure if you intended to set `$user` and do a conditional at one here.

I might suggest getting in the habit of writing condditionals like this:

```
if (true === $member) { ... }
```

By inverting the order of the items, if you ever accidentally type `=` instead of `==` or `===`, then you will get an error, instead of having the code silently perform unexpectedly.

Comment: I guess I don't see the scope issue here as I am not familiar with Joomla and don't have any context for this code outside what is shown.

Comment: yeah, i thought so, so i removed my comment, even though it still won't work. but you gave him good advices

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I declare in start the $member = false; but then I change the value of $member depending on whether the person is logged in. So the if statement can take a decision.

Comment: @StanMarsh The problem is that first if statement I showed in my answer is not making a decision, it is setting the value of `$member` to `true`, which will always make the condition evaluate as `true` you need `==` or `===` instead of `=` in the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a scope issue here: you are declaring $member in a module, but $member won't be available to the article: and php will evaluate ($something == false) to always succeed if $something is undefined, if you want to check if a variable is *really* false you need to use ($something===false). Read more here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

That being said, since there is no real overhead to JFactory::getUser()->guest, just use that as well in you article!

btw, enable notices in your php configuration (either on screen or to a log file) and make sure you read that as you develop, it will tell you whatever is wrong, developing without seeing the errors is a guessing game, you can only bang your head against the wall so many times... you eventually need to switch on the light :-)